# How to use Perl to parse Verilog code to identify registers being assigned?

Tags: regex, perl, parsing, syntax, verilog

======== Feb. 1, 2016 edit ========

Eventually solved the problem with the help of an anonymous buddy:

```
while ($verilog_code =~ /\/\/.*?\n|(\w+)\s*<=\s*.*?;/smgx) {
        if(defined $1) {
                push (@regs, $1);
                ｝
        ｝

foreach (0..$#regs) {
        print "\@regs[$_]= @regs[$_]\n";
        }
```

Use two matches: one for the comment, which "jumps over" the unwanted comments; another match for the assignment syntax, which captures the stuff I want. The result is as follows, which is what I expect:

```
@regs[0]= ak47
@regs[1]= ak48
@regs[2]= ak49
@regs[3]= ak50
@regs[4]= ak53
@regs[5]= ak54
```

Again, thanks to all :)

======== Following is the original post ========

My first post on StackOverflow, appreciations to anyone who may help.

I'm using Perl to parse Verilog source code and identify all registers assigned in a block. The Verilog assignment syntax is like " reg_data <= din ;", which means "reg_data is assigned the value of din".

As Verilog code become more complicated, Perl parsing becomes difficult. For example (defined in Perl variable $verilog_code):

```
my $verilog_code = "
if (s1) ak47 <= din; ak48
        <= d48; // my comment
else if (s2) begin
        // comments
        ak49 <= d49; ak50 <= d50; // ak51 <= d51 ; ak52 <= d52; // comments
        ak53 <=
                d5+d3; 
        end
else ak54 <= ((d<=e) ? (d540) : d541) ; 
        // comment: ak55 <= d55 ; 
";
```

In it, some specific cases are covered:

1. One line of code may contain many assignments, eg. ak47 and ak48 share the same line, ak49 and ak50 share the same line, etc.
2. One assignment may span many lines, eg. both ak48 and ak53 occupy two lines.
3. Line comments starting with "//" may appear at the beginning or the middle of a line; anything within comments should be ignored.

Consequently, for $verilog_code, assignments for ak47, ak48, ak49, ak50, ak53 and ak54 should be identified, while ak51, ak52 and ak55 should be ignored. I made many attempts, using Perl regular expression (regex) to parse the text, but none of them worked so far:

```
@reg_assignments = $verilog_code =~ m/(?<!\/\/\s*)(\w+\s*<=.*?;)/sg;
```

====> this one reports error "Variable length lookbehind not implemented in regex".

```
@reg_assignments = $verilog_code =~ m/(?<!\/\/ )(\b\w+\b\s*<=.*?;)/sg;
```

====> this one gets me the following result:

```
@reg_assignments[0]= ak47 <= din;
@reg_assignments[1]= ak48
        <= d48;
@reg_assignments[2]= ak49 <= d49;
@reg_assignments[3]= ak50 <= d50;
@reg_assignments[4]= ak52 <= d52;
@reg_assignments[5]= ak53 <=
                d5+d3;
@reg_assignments[6]= ak54 <= ((d<=e) ? (d540) : d541) ;
@reg_assignments[7]= ak55 <= d55 ;
```

----> Here, assignment for ak51 is successfully ignored, but ak52 and ak55 are mistakenly captured.

```
@reg_assignments = $verilog_code =~ m/(?<!\/\/)(?:[^\n]*?(\b\w+\s*<=.*?;))/sg ;
```

====> This one gets the following result:

```
@reg_assignments[0]= ak47 <= din;
@reg_assignments[1]= ak48
        <= d48;
@reg_assignments[2]= ak49 <= d49;
@reg_assignments[3]= ak50 <= d50;
@reg_assignments[4]= ak51 <= d51 ;
@reg_assignments[5]= ak52 <= d52;
@reg_assignments[6]= ak53 <=
                d5+d3;
@reg_assignments[7]= ak54 <= ((d<=e) ? (d540) : d541) ;
@reg_assignments[8]= ak55 <= d55 ;
```

I just want to extract all the effective assignments in a Verilog text, excluding the stuffs within comments. The solution has been eluding me for days. Can anyone give me any hints on how to implement this? Thx ~

Comment: Have you searched [CPAN](https://metacpan.org/search?size=500&q=Verilog&search_type=modules) for "Verilog"?

Comment: Thanks guys. At the beginning I've been thinking about just manually crafting an ad-hoc verilog parser; now I'll try the CPAN Verilog stuff. Here I used illegal Verilog syntax only in a handy "test" Perl script; I'll convert to legal syntax in the "real" Perl stuff. Thanks again :P

Comment: @katyusza, great that you solved the problem. I would recommend posting your solution in the answer section instead of updating the question. Then accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to suggestion from @Greg, I'm just posting the solution down here, in case someone else might need it. And many appreciations to Perl Dog who take the time to help me :-)

======== Feb. 1, 2016 edit ========

Eventually solved the problem with the help of an anonymous buddy:

```
while ($verilog_code =~ /\/\/.*?\n|(\w+)\s*<=\s*.*?;/smgx) {
        if(defined $1) {
                push (@regs, $1);
                ｝
        ｝

foreach (0..$#regs) {
        print "\@regs[$_]= @regs[$_]\n";
        }
```

Use two matches: one for the comment, which "jumps over" the unwanted comments; another match for the assignment syntax, which captures the stuff I want. The result is as follows, which is what I expect:

```
@regs[0]= ak47
@regs[1]= ak48
@regs[2]= ak49
@regs[3]= ak50
@regs[4]= ak53
@regs[5]= ak54
```

Again, thanks to all :)

Answer (score 1):

If your verilog code is really that simple and you dont't want to install some modules and perfomance doesn't really matter, then I'd suggest two or three steps:

- strip off any comments:

  `$verilog_code =~ s:^(.*?)//.*$:$1:mg;`
- optional: get rid of newlines:

  `$verilog_code =~ s/\n//g;`
- get the assignments:

  `my @assignments = ($verilog_code =~ /\S+\s*<=[^;]+;/g);`

  This is all non-whitepace, followed by `<=` up to the next `;`.

This gives

```
@assignments = (
                 'ak47 <= din;',
                 'ak48        <= d48;',
                 'ak49 <= d49;',
                 'ak50 <= d50;',
                 'ak53 <=                d5+d3;',
                 'ak54 <= ((d<=e) ? (d540) : d541) ;'
               );
```

Comment: thx for the advice; you're right that the verilog code is simple (because it's just an ad-hoc Perl script), I don't want to install some modules, and performance really does NOT matter. But the problem is that I don't want to strip off the comments (because sometimes they DO provide useful information), and I DO want to keep the newlines which keeps a nice formatting for Verilog code. Any further suggestions~? 3q~ :P

Comment: Ah, ok. But then the solution you put into your OP is not really a solution. ;-)

Comment: -,- I know it's ad-hoc and ugly. Get any comments on some little improvements?